# Shared dict that gets filled by separate processes

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to divide a process that takes a 20k items array, periodically computes the element of the array and fills a global dict with the current result of that processing, into multiple processes.

my issue is the return dict as i need it to be in a single place in order to later on and periodically send it in it's entirety via an HTTP call.

my reasoning is to have the dict in the main process/thread and divide the 20k items into chunks over 4 processes, each having about 500 threads with each thread processing a number of items, but it seems I can't just pass a global variable to all processes and have that be filled, as each process creates an empty variable and I get nothing in my global variable.

I had the idea of making each process send their result via HTTP to a server and that would buffer the results and then send the entire dict to the destination. but that would introduce huge latency which is not desirable.

how can I achieve the division? is there any way that i can buffer the results coming from the multiple processes with the most reduced latency? the global variable must be a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot share variables between subprocesses, or at least, it is not particularly easy. I am also not sure why you would need this for this problem.

Have you considered using Pythons `multiprocessing.Pool` functionality? [Its official documentation with examples can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Each thread therein could process a subset of your input `dict`. After execution, `multiprocessing.Pool` would return a list of the output of each process, with the list having a length equal to the number of threads used. You can merge the separate outputs into a single `dict()` once all the processes have finished to gather all data into a single dict(). Would that work?

Comment: it wouldn't really be the case as the processes would actually need to continue running. the processing is infinite. each process will have to continue periodically process the same input while continuing to output new results. so the processes never finish so that the pool would be able to return my processed data.

Comment: The main process can call `multiprocessor.Manager().dict()` to return a *proxy* to a shared `dict`. This proxy can be passed as an argument to your process pool worker function, which can update the shared dictionary. Being a proxy, each update of the dictionary is essentially a remote procedure call so don't expect the same performance as a *regular* `dict`. If you need a *regular* `dict` later on, you can construct one from the proxy: `shared_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` and then later `regular_dict = dict(shared_dict)`